# change state with the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a function that selects a period in a calendar and converts it to a from and to object, I need to set a state with the information that returns from this function when changing the calendar

```
const [ eventdate, setEventDate ] = useState({ from: '', to: ''})

 const updateDate = (period) => {
    const room = period
    return room
}

useEffect(() => {
    setEventDate(room)
}), [room]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is buggy but still as per my understanding

No need to use the useeffect , directly set the component state i.e eventDate in the updateDate function.
And useEffect will not work here because in the array you have to pass the local states and only changing the state will make it run and room is not the state in your case